# How to rotate y axis surface in famo.us such that both sides appear while rotating?

Tags: angularjs, famo.us

I rotate a surface upon the y axis but half of the rotation is hidden, i mean that the flip of the surface image not shown in the rotation, just half of the rotation.
my code:

```
  var angle = 5;
  $scope.rotate = function(){
  angle += 0.05;
  return Transform.rotateY(angle);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Surface needs backface-visibility

**Here is the css:**

```
.double-sided {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

**[You can see from this jsbin Example](http://jsbin.com/tidemipodosi/1/edit) how it is applied.**

Comment: Can you check this question too please?!, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25501680/how-to-remove-height-overflow-in-scrollview-surfaces, thank you in advance.